# How to use different CSS and routes in nodeJS for mobile?

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap, express

We are developing a web application in nodeJS for which when access with a mobile device we need to render different views in our routing using different CSS.
How can one detect and implement this?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very big, complex question, and it's not really "nodejs" specfic, but I'll try to take a shot an answering.

The current best practices are to use [feature detection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_detection_%28web_development%29) and [responsive design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design) to produce the mobile interface.

With CSS3, it's possible to use [Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) to determine how HTML elements should be displayed on screen, based on various properties of the device in use (resolution, pixel density, orientation, "handheld", etc.)

You can go further and use feature detection to determine which features to load. Checking if "ontouchstart" can be defined on an element, would be a good way to know if touch events were (or were not) supported. Libraries like [yepnope](http://yepnopejs.com/) were designed to make this easy.

In many cases, this will be adequate -- and as I said, these are the current best practices.

However, In a few cases, you may actually want to produce a different HTML structure. Depending on whether you're using client-side templates (as happens frequently in "SPA" apps), or rendering on the server, I think you have at least three different options, both essentially still depend on the information above:

*Option A:* Use feature detection to determine if you're "on mobile" (whatever that means for you), then request the "mobile" templates from the server via a special URL that includes a "isMobile" flag, like "/clientTemplates?isMobile=true".

*Option B:* Use feature detection to determine if you're "on mobile". You can then set a cookie, or "X-Client-Type"-type header that indicates whether you're "on mobile", then, in your express middleware, you can use a convention like the following:

```
app.use('/apath', function(req, res){
    //get the type of client
    var view_type = req.headers['X-Client-Type'] || 'desktop';
    var model = {};
    //by convention, "apath_mobile" or "apath_desktop" 
    //will be rendered based on this header.
    res.render('apath_' + view_type, model);
}
```

*Option C:* Use the (*unreliable*) "User-Agent" header to determine whether the client making the request is "mobile" -- again, this is typically not a good way to do this type of checking. Once you have determined "desktop" or "mobile", you can use the same type of technique as described in Option B.

Again, I highly, highly recommend you look at feature detection and responsive design, as they are much more elegant solutions to this problem, and are the longer-term solution to this.