# Change colour background of a div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So today I have been learning how to use Bootstrap(I'm very new) and I have come across a bit of a problem. This is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Home</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Home</a>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="jumbotron text-center">
        <h1>Welcome!</h1>
        <p>Random text here that doesn't matter</p>
        <a class="btn btn-default">Watch now!</a>
        <a class="btn btn-info">Tweet it</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom">
    <div class="container">
      <p class="navbar-text pull-left">Site created: 30/05/16</p>
      <a href="http://www.youtube.com" class="navbar-btn btn-danger btn pull-right">Subscribe on YouTube</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

and basically everything is fine however, if you view my code as .html or whatever in a browser, you will see that under the navigation menu at the top which is black, there is the jumbotron which is fine however, the background of it is black which I don't want, I want it to be white like the rest of the page. I'm so new to this so I can't even manage to figure out how to do this so any help would be highley appreciated. Sorry, I've tried to be as specific as I can but I really am new to this and I'm hoping someone can help me.

TH.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [is possible to change background color using bootstrap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31731394/is-possible-to-change-background-color-using-bootstrap)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get

```
<div class="container">
<div class="jumbotron text-center">
<h1>Welcome!</h1>
<p>Random text here that doesn't matter</p>
<a class="btn btn-default">Watch now!</a>
<a class="btn btn-info">Tweet it</a>
</div>
</div>
```

outside of

nav tags

You do not have to make any changes in CSS

Answer (score 0):

Hope i understood you right. If you DONT want to change any html markup you just need to change the color by adding a custom css class to the desired elements and override what boostrap does:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse myJumbotronColor">
  <div class="container-fluid myNavBarColor">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Home</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron text-center">
      <h1>Welcome!</h1>
      <p>Random text here that doesn't matter</p>
      <a class="btn btn-default">Watch now!</a>
      <a class="btn btn-info">Tweet it</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom">
  <div class="container">
    <p class="navbar-text pull-left">Site created: 30/05/16</p>
    <a href="http://www.youtube.com" class="navbar-btn btn-danger btn pull-right">Subscribe on YouTube</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the custom css:

```
.myNavBarColor {
  background-color: rgb(34, 34, 34);
  border-color: rgb(8, 8, 8);
}
.myJumbotronColor {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: none;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6gnp4doL/

Please note that you have a markup error in your html:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
    <!-- these two tag should not be here
    </ul>
    </li> -->
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use css for the navbar color but still I am confused what actually you want:

```
 .navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle {
        background-color: #efefef;
    }
    .navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle:hover {
        background-color: #efefef;
    }
```

[JSfiddle for the same](https://jsfiddle.net/4xxpLqdv/)

Answer (score 0):

Put the `container` div outside the `nav`.

Here:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Home</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Home</a>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="jumbotron text-center">
        <h1>Welcome!</h1>
        <p>Random text here that doesn't matter</p>
        <a class="btn btn-default">Watch now!</a>
        <a class="btn btn-info">Tweet it</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom">
    <div class="container">
      <p class="navbar-text pull-left">Site created: 30/05/16</p>
      <a href="http://www.youtube.com" class="navbar-btn btn-danger btn pull-right">Subscribe on YouTube</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can seek which element has the actual background.
Than go to your CSS file ( assuming you made one ) and set the background color to white.
Let's assume the nav-bar header class has the background color to it

Add this to your CSS file

```
    .nav-bar
    {
         background-color: white !imporant;
    }
```

The !important is to override any other style sheet lines written to adjust the property on the element.

Comment: No the OP has just put the container `<div>` in `<nav>`.